# Sum of the four 32bits elements of a _m128 vector

Tags: sum, simd, sse2, sse3

I'm using intrinsics to optimize a program of mine. But now I would like to sum the four elements that are in a __m128 vector in order to compare the result to a floating point value. For instance, let's say I have this 128 bits vector : {a, b c, d}. How can I compare a+b+c+d to e, where e is of type float ?

Does SSE2 or SSE3 provide a way to do that simply or do you have any code snippet that could help me ? Thanks !

Comment: You could do that in SSE3 with two HADDPS's, but that's not very fast. Where does this vector come from? Can whatever calculates it be rearranged such that a horizontal addition could be avoided?

Comment: Well I must compare (a*a + b*b) and 4.0. To do this, I've stored a and b in a __m128 vector, such as vec = {a, b, UNUSED, UNUSED}.
I obtain {a², b², X, X} by doing square = _mm_mul_ps(vec, vec). And now,  I'm searching for a way to get a² + b² so that I can compare it to 4.0.
That's certainly not optimal, so if you have any advice, it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I don't have SSE4 support on my processor, sorry.

Comment: That's a shame, DPPS was a real good fit for this problem. Ok, I'll have to think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can up with is this:

```
; assumes    xmm0 = [0, B, 0, A] or similar
mulps xmm0,xmm0   ; [0, B*B, 0, A*A]
xorps xmm1,xmm1
movhlps xmm1,xmm0 ; [0, 0, 0, B * B]
addps xmm0,xmm1   ; [0, 0, 0, A * A + B * B]
```

If A and B absolutely have to be in the low quadword then as far as I can tell you need a shuffle, which is slower on pre-Penryn (and on a Penryn the DPPS solution is available).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But now that I have this vector, how to compare it to 4. ? Should I create a vector that would contain {0, 0, 0, 4} and compare  them with _mm_cmpeq_ss ?

Comment: If you want, but this is floating point so it doesn't really mix well with the EQ variant. What's it for? Can the comparison be replaced by a LE or NLT variant?

Comment: Well in fact, I could as well use LE. Thanks for your help !